# Tensor product of polynomial ring with itself

Tags: modules, tensor-products, tensors

I have two questions with regards to taking tensor products of polynomial rings.

First, when I thought about $$\mathbb{F}[X] \otimes_\mathbb{F} \mathbb{F}[X],$$ I thought, wrongly of course, that it is $$\cong \mathbb{F}[X].$$ I want to intuitively understand why this is wrong. I thought the isomorphism is just $$f(x) \otimes g(x) \mapsto f(x)g(x).$$ The problem here is that you can pull-through not just scalars, but even $x$, i.e. under this map, $xf \otimes g = f \otimes xg$. I am only taking the tensor product over $\mathbb{F}$, so this is wrong. Is my reasoning correct here?

Second, is it true that $$\mathbb{F}[X] \otimes_{\mathbb{F}[X]} \mathbb{F}[X] \cong \mathbb{F}[X]?$$

Comment: It's true in general for any commutative ring $R$ and an $R$-module $M$ that $M\otimes_R R \simeq M$, and since $R$ is an $R$-module then it certainly is true that $R\otimes_R R\simeq R$.

Comment: For intuition, in $F[x] \otimes_F F[x]$ use different letters for the indeterminates: $F[x] \otimes_F F[y]$. That would make you hesitate before bringing an indeterminate from one side to the other.  However, it is *false* that it's always wrong to transfer a scaling factor $c$ from one side to the other in $M \otimes_R N$ just because $c \not\in R$. If $R$ is an integral domain with fraction field $K$ and $V$ and $W$ are $K$-vector spaces, then in $V \otimes_R W$, $cv \otimes w = v \otimes cw$ for $c \in K$. See Theorem 6.19 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf.

Comment: Actually, it is known that for any $R$-algebra $S$, one has the isomorphism $S\otimes_R R[X]\simeq S[X]$. I f we take $S=R[Y]$, we obtain $ R[Y]\otimes_R R[X]\simeq (R[Y])[X] \simeq R[X,Y]$,

Comment: @KCd Theorem 6.19 is very interesting. I wondered if it was true because in some sense $K$ is finitely generated over $R$, and $R[X]$ is not, but then in the document, there's the example of how you cannot pull through a complex number, so what I said doesn't make sense. It would be interesting to have some necessary conditions on when you can transfer factors from one side to the other.

Comment: In what sense do you mean $K$ is "finitely generated" over $R$?  For example, $\mathbf Q$ is not a finitely generated $\mathbf Z$-module and it is also not a finitely generated $\mathbf Z$-algebra.  Meanwhile, $R[X]$ is not a finitely generated $R$-module but is a finitely generated $R$-algebra.

Comment: In a very hand-wavy sense, apologies. $Q \cong (Z \times Z) / \sim$, so when I said finite, I meant there are just two $Z$s.

Comment: You can also see the difference categorically. That is, in the category of $\mathbb F$ algebras, the covariant hom functors of $\mathbb F[x]$ and $\mathbb F[x] \otimes_{\mathbb F} \mathbb F[x]$ are different, so by the Yoneda lemma they are not isomorphic as $\mathbb F$ algebras. This approach also hints that the correct isomorphism is to $\mathbb F[x, y]$ by comparing universal properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue indeed is that you can't pull non-scalars across the tensor symbol (without some other theorem that might apply in certain scenarios, like what @KCd mentions).

Here's a way to see that $\mathbb{F}[X]\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}\mathbb{F}[X]$ can't possibly be isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}[X]$:

- First, let's define an $\mathbb{F}$-bilinear function $\mathbb{F}[X]\times \mathbb{F}[X] \to \mathbb{F}[X_1,X_2]$ with $(X^m,X^n)\mapsto X_1^mX_2^n$ for all $m,n\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ (verification of well-definedness and bilinearity left to the reader), and hence there is a corresponding $\mathbb{F}$-linear map $\mathbb{F}[X]\otimes_{\mathbb{F}} \mathbb{F}[X] \to \mathbb{F}[X_1,X_2]$ by the universal property of tensor products.  The map is certainly surjective.  For injectivity, suppose $\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} X^i\otimes X^j$ were in the kernel.  The image is $\sum_{i,j} c_{ij} X_1^iX_2^j$, and since polynomials let us read off coefficients, we see each $c_{ij}$ is $0$.
  Hence the map is an isomorphism.
- Second, if there were an isomorphism $\mathbb{F}[X]\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}\mathbb{F}[X]\cong \mathbb{F}[X]$, by composing isomorphisms we would have an isomorphism $\mathbb{F}[X_1,X_2]\cong\mathbb{F}[X]$.  Assuming $\mathbb{F}$ is a field (since you're using that letter) or at least a Noetherian ring, then by either using transcendence degree of the fraction field or Krull dimension, we get a contradiction.

It is true that $\mathbb{F}[X]\otimes_{\mathbb{F}[X]}\mathbb{F}[X]\cong \mathbb{F}[X]$, and more generally $R\otimes_RR\cong R$ for any (unital) ring whatsoever, commutative or noncommutative.  By going through the same universal property of tensor products, we can define an $R$-linear map $R\otimes_R R\to R$ such that $1\otimes 1\mapsto 1$, and it is an isomorphism.  Concretely, the isomorphism has the formula $\sum_{i,j} a_i\otimes b_j \mapsto \sum_{i,j}a_ib_j$.